# Missing entities when JOIN between differencce layer to origianl layer in SQL QGIS3

Tags: qgis-3, sql, attribute-joins

I have two layers :
1. layer of fake plots
2. layer that shows only the safe area inside those plots (generated with the Difference tool), and contains data about the area of each safe polygon.

this is how the layers look like:

layer no. 1:

[image]

Layer 2:

[image]

I want to join the information from layer 2 (safe area) to layer 1, so for each plot I  can know the size of the safe area,including plots that are not safe at all (that don't have safe area)
for that I have tried to do left outer join in qgis as following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "Lease" LEFT OUTER JOIN "safe"
WHERE "Lease"."OBJECTID"="safe"."OBJECTID"
```

the join worked but in the result table I don't have all my original plots- I have 30 plots but here you can see in the result that some plots are missing( 16,17 and 21):
[image]

and the plots that are missing are the ones that don't have "safe" area.

how can I get back those lost plots so they will appear in my table, even if they get null or 0?

**My endgoal: to have one table with al the entities from the original plot layer, with the data about the  size of the safe area, even if there is no safe area, so I can claculate the precentage of sade area in each plot.**

Comment: @TARAS I couldn't open the link. and when I tried what you wrote I got the same results

Comment: Sorry ... I meant `...LEFT JOIN "safe" ON "Lease"."OBJECTID"="safe"."OBJECTID"`

Comment: that's the same result and as I did

Comment: are you sure that `LEFT JOIN` does no do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a condition `ON` the join, not in the `where`.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM "Lease" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "safe"
  ON "Lease"."OBJECTID"="safe"."OBJECTID"
```

Doing so do the join based on the `objectid` and keep all rows from the 1st table.

As you did with the `where` clause, it is doing a full cross-join on both table and then the `where` keeps only the matching rows (i.e. it is not a LEFT join anymore)

Comment: thank you @JGH , it works, but do you know if there is any possibility to show it in the sql query builder? because when I write it there, the left outer join "jumps" into the FROM line.

Comment: @Reut it should be fine in the "from" / "table". What matters is the resulting query, not how it is shown in the query builder